# Which statement is true about the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Suppose $f(x)$ is a positive, continuous, and decreasing function such that $\int_{100}^\infty f(x)  dx $ is finite. Which of the following statements about $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$ is true?

$(a)$  It must converge.
$(b)$  It must diverge. 
$(c)$  It might either converge or diverge; we need more information to know for sure.

I think the series converges because a series is just a constant plus the other one. Therefore, if one converges, so does the other. (So the answer above would be $(a)$. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that for functions such as $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ this doesn't quite work, but $f$ isn't positive or decreasing! So this is just application of the integral test.

Answer (score 0):

The integral $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_0^{100} f(x)dx + \int_{100}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ is convergent because the two terms are finite: the first one is finite because the function is continuous so by the extreme value theorem it attains a maximum and a minimum on $[0,100]$. So by [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) also the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent.

Comment: Why is $\int_0^{100}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ finite? I was the one who downvoted, but I soon realized that I misread the question but couldn't cancel the downvote anymore.

Comment: You're right that convergence follows from integral test, but $\int_0^{100}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't have to converge

Comment: mmh I think it shoud converge by the extreme value theorem

Comment: You're right, still, it's a bit unnecessary to include this interval $[0, 100]$, convergence doesn't depend on a finite amount of terms.

Comment: yes, but it could have been divergent if it was unbounded in one of the points inside the interval so for clarity I added it